# How to focus on layout itself?

Tags: android, view

I have a family of layouts in my login view.
I would like to focus on the login form itself, meaning that its text boxes are centered and in focus.

Currently when I start the activity and click on the login text box, the app doesn't focus on the form. It is still showing the whole view.

[image: My login view structure]

[image: Login view]

I tried

- Requesting focus for the login form: No success.
- Making the login form focusable: No success.

Comment: Have you tried requestFocus() or <requestFocus />?

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "the app doesn't focus on the form. It is still showing the whole view." ?

When you click on the Login TextBox, the textbox (EditText) gets the focus.

Comment: I want the app to focus on the form only, currently the  view doesn't focus (zoom) to the form. Only the keyboard appears.

Comment: yes. that's the default behavior. When you click on the EditText, it gets the focus and the Keyboard comes up so the user can type something. Is this not what you want ?

Comment: Android doesn't not do any zooming in when you focus the Layout. If this is the case, I think you should rethink your design. Zooming in and out for layouts seems to have a negative effect on the users.

Answer (score 0):

You could animate your layout to grow.